# Adding dropdown on the wicket frame work with scala code

Tags: scala, wicket

How to add a dropdown on the webpage with wicket framework also using scala code and save the data into the database with correct select type

Comment: Can you add your code what you tried?

Comment: The very same way as you would do it with Java.